# Using jQuery need to hide only certain cell in a table

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have this table in http://jsfiddle.net/RwvN5/12/ what I need to do is hide only the first cell when clicking on the last cell. Only need to hide ONE cell in the same row when clicking on the trigger.

HTML:

```
<table id="dynamicTable">
<tr>
    <td id="hidesme">need to hide</td>
    <td><a href="https:\\www.google.com\">Click Here</a></td>
    <td><a href="https:\\www.google.com\">Click Here</a></td>
    <td><a href="https:\\www.google.com\">Click Here</a></td>
    <td class="trigger">trigger</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="Gray">
    <td id="hidesme">need to hide</td>
    <td><a href="https:\\www.google.com\">Click Here</a></td>
    <td><a href="https:\\www.google.com\">Click Here</a></td>
    <td><a href="https:\\www.google.com\">Click Here</a></td>
    <td class="trigger">trigger</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="hidesme">need to hide</td>
    <td><a href="https:\\www.google.com\">Click Here</a></td>
    <td><a href="https:\\www.google.com\">Click Here</a></td>
    <td><a href="https:\\www.google.com\">Click Here</a></td>
    <td class="trigger">trigger</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="Gray">
    <td id="hidesme">need to hide</td>
    <td><a href="https:\\www.google.com\">Click Here</a></td>
    <td><a href="https:\\www.google.com\">Click Here</a></td>
    <td><a href="https:\\www.google.com\">Click Here</a></td>
    <td class="trigger">trigger</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".trigger").click(function () {
        var myelement = $(this).find('#hidesme');
        alert("HI");
        $(myelement).toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: General idea for most computing is IDs should always be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `parent().find("#hidesme")` since this is TD where you can't find the first TD. So find the parent TR and from that find first td.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".trigger").click(function () {

        var myelement = $(this).parent().find('#hidesme');
        alert("HI");
        $(myelement).toggle();

    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RwvN5/14/)**

Answer (score 0):

`Id` should be unique.

Try,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".trigger").click(function () {          
        var myelement = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first');
        myelement.toggle();         
    });
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/RwvN5/15/)

Answer (score 0):

Id is unique so remove id="hidesme"

and try the following code

```
$(".trigger").click(function (){

            $(this).parent().find('td:first').toggle();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(".trigger").click(function () {
       $(this).parent().find('td:first-child' ).toggle();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RwvN5/18/)

Answer (score -1):

`id` should be unique, you need to use class instead for your `td`:

```
<td class="hidesme">need to hide</td>
```

Then you can use [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings) to hide your `td`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".trigger").click(function () {  
        $(this).closest('td').siblings('.hidesme').hide();
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RwvN5/17/)**